# SQL Min and Count

Tags: sql, oracle, count, min

What I'm trying to achieve is to display the count number of books in categories

Where Count(Category) > Minimum number in Count(Category)

Example;

If categories are

```
A = 1
b = 2
c = 3
D = 1
E = 1
```

I'm trying to show the categories which are > 1 using MIN.

The error I'm getting is:

> ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply

```
SELECT Count(Category),
       Category 
From Books
Having Count((Category) > MIN(Count(Category)
Group BY Category
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking for something like this:

```
Select Count(Category),
       Category 
From Books 
Group BY Category 
Having Count(Category) > (Select Min(cnt)
                          from (Select Count(Category) AS cnt
                                From Books
                                Group By Category))
```

This will select all categories having a count that is greater than the minimum count among all categories.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to `rank` by count starting with the lowest (ties are assigned the same rank) and to only select rows with rank greater than 1:

```
select * from (
    select count(*) cnt, category,
      rank() over (order by count(*)) rn
    from books
    group by category  
) t where rn > 1
```

Comment: If the base table is very large, this solution is inefficient since it ranks all categories by count, rather than simply finding the smallest count. Ordering the whole set is much more work than finding the min.

Comment: @mathguy I disagree. Using rank will be much faster on larger tables than doing 2 group by statements on the entire table. Give it a try.

Comment: Why would you need two group by statements? You only need one (unless you count selecting min from an entire table as a "group by").

Comment: @mathguy see accepted answer, which gives equivalent results to this answer. Op basically wants to exclude groups that have the min count

Comment: The answer is equivalent (meaning the same result) but the operations involved are NOT equivalent. The accepted answer does not order all categories by their count, as `rank()` does.

Comment: Right ... the accepted answer uses 2 group by statements which is slower than using 1 plus rank

Comment: Hehe - that is why I added an answer when there were already several good answers - to show that only one "group by" statement suffices, by factoring the subquery.

Comment: I think cte is simply shorthand. Your answer is identical to the accepted one and will still run group by twice.

Comment: @mathguy see http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13112/whats-the-difference-between-a-cte-and-a-temp-table

Comment: I'll drop out of this conversation, since it seems we don't speak the same language. Your link is to something about SQL Server. At least in Oracle, if you replace a subquery used more than once in your main query as a CTE, it will be evaluated only once. There is plenty of Oracle documentation about (Oracle) CTE's. For example, see the mention of treating a CTE as a "temporary table": http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142

Comment: @mathguy I didn't see anything in the link stating that oracle only runs cte once ... let's agree to disagree then

Comment: Perhaps "temporary table" has a different meaning between Oracle and SQL Server, too.

Comment: @mathguy the same sentence you refer to also mentions treating cte as an "inline view" ... perhaps the best way to test is to simply look at the query plans

Comment: Right - planning to do so. The optimizer has the ability to treat the CTE as a temp table if it sees fit. In this case it should see fit to treat it as a temp table. Will test.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
 SELECT Category, CategoryCount from
 (SELECT rownum as r, Category, Count(*) as CategoryCount
 From Books 
 Group BY Category
 Order by CategoryCount asc)
 Where r > 1;
```

Comment: this eliminates only one row of the rows with minimum category count

Comment: yeah, nice catch Turo. Yes, this just eliminates the one row. Giorgos answer is the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Giorgos's answer is the correct one. It can be rearranged (and made slightly more efficient) using subquery factoring:

```
with ctg (category, categ_count) as (
        select   category, count(*)
        from     books
        group by category
     )
select category, categ_count
from   ctg
where  categ_count > (select min(categ_count) from ctg);
```